# How to close Android Browser after loading PHP file in android device

Tags: javascript, php, android

I have tried using the following code in my **php** file

```
<script>
    window.open('', '_self', ''); 
    window.close(); 
</script>
```

the code runs fine in windows browser and gets closed when respective php file is loaded
but if the same php file is loaded in the android device browser the browser is not closed.

I have tried using

```
<script>
    self.close();
</script>
```

Comment: two things, you dont load php files into browsers, they load the html output coming from them... and second im pretty sure that you cant do that in mobiles. since they work differently